# Using ajax.actionlink in mvc4 causes to refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<DomainClasses.Class>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "لیست ";
}
<div id="test">
<h2>لیست کلاس ها</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("ایجاد کلاس جدید", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
           @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClassName)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClassName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @*@Html.ActionLink("ویرایش", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |*@
            @Ajax.ActionLink("ویرایش1","Edit",new { id=item.Id },new AjaxOptions(){UpdateTargetId = "test",InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,HttpMethod = "GET"})
            @Html.ActionLink("حذف", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
    </div>
```

As you can see I created a `div` named **test**, and I make an ajax action link:

```
  @Ajax.ActionLink("ویرایش1","Edit",new { id=item.Id },new AjaxOptions(){UpdateTargetId = "test",InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,HttpMethod = "GET"})
```

So when I click on the link that I created by ajax `actionlink` my page is refreshed and my url changed to **localhost/Class/Edit/1**. Why does this happen? I thought my page shouldn't be refreshed!

Best regards

Comment: I would actually suggest doing this using jQuery rather than MVC.

Comment: This would point that either you are missing the correct javascript files or you have a javascript error somewhere on the page.  Does firebug or chrome dev tools show any errors in the console?

Comment: @Tommy no it doesn't .i don't have any error

Comment: @No1_Melman - The Ajax.ActionLink uses the jquery.unobtrisuve-ajax script to AJAXify the anchor behind the scenes.

Comment: It may be because you are replacing the content container containing the AJAX firing link - what if you had your target div just at the top, like `<div id="test2"></div>`

Comment: @Tommy indeed, but I mean straight up writing it.

Comment: @Tommy i did that but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js script included on your view. If you don't here is the nuget package http://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Ajax.Unobtrusive/2.0.20710. When you install the package make sure that jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js is included in your view.

Comment: I added to my layout view but the same problem :        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

Comment: I assume you are 100% sure that jquery.unobtrusive-ajax loads successfully on the page? You verified with Firebug or chrome Dev tools? Try including it this way: <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")">

Comment: Yes i sure ,I linked the script with this way ,but same problem

Comment: Which JS libraries are included on your page? for this tow work you need to have jquery included as well. Also do you see any client side javascript errors?